# Prove a the convergence of a series in dual Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose we have a series where $\{u_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset X'$, $u\in X'$, and this satisfies $u_{n}\xrightarrow{w^{*}} u.$ Where X is the Banach Space over $F$. Is $\|u\|_{X'}\leq \lim\limits inf $ ${n \to \infty} \|u_{n}\|_{X'}?$

Comment: There is no reason why the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} |u_n|_{X'}$ should exist.

Answer (score 0):

By uniform boundedness principle it follows that $(u_n)$ is bounded in $X'$. Moreover,
$$
u(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} u_n(x)
$$
implies
$$
|u(x)| \le \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} |u_n(x)| \le \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} \|u_n\|_{X'} \|x\|,
$$
which shows
$$
\|u\|\le \lim\inf_{n\to\infty} \|u_n\|_{X'} .
$$